# Function XOpenDisplay with and without parameter

Tags: c, linux, xlib

I have little issue with XOpenDisplay function. In school I can run program and it works good when using XOpenDisplay("ip:0"), but on my local machine in home when I run program (changed ip on current) got "Segmentation fault (core dumped)", but with empy string XOpenDisplay("") it works fine. I need to be able to use ip. Used host +, but nothing changes. 
My system is Kubuntu 14.04.1: 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015

Here is code of program:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <stdio.h>

Display *mydisplay;
Window mywindow;
XSetWindowAttributes mywindowattributes;
XGCValues mygcvalues;
GC mygc;
Visual *myvisual;
int mydepth;
int myscreen;
Colormap mycolormap;
XColor mycolor,mycolor1,dummy;
int i;

main()

{
  mydisplay = XOpenDisplay("192.168.0.12:0");
  myscreen = DefaultScreen(mydisplay);
  myvisual = DefaultVisual(mydisplay,myscreen);
  mydepth = DefaultDepth(mydisplay,myscreen);
  mywindowattributes.background_pixel = XWhitePixel(mydisplay,myscreen);
  mywindowattributes.override_redirect = True;

  mywindow = XCreateWindow(mydisplay,XRootWindow(mydisplay,myscreen),
                        0,0,500,500,10,mydepth,InputOutput,
                        myvisual,CWBackPixel|CWOverrideRedirect,
                        &mywindowattributes);

  mycolormap = DefaultColormap(mydisplay,myscreen);                 

  XAllocNamedColor(mydisplay,mycolormap,"cyan",&mycolor,&dummy);

    XAllocNamedColor(mydisplay,mycolormap,"red",&mycolor1,&dummy);                 

  XMapWindow(mydisplay,mywindow);

  mygc = DefaultGC(mydisplay,myscreen);

  XSetForeground(mydisplay,mygc,mycolor.pixel);

  XFillRectangle(mydisplay,mywindow,mygc,100,100,300,300);

  XSetForeground(mydisplay,mygc,mycolor1.pixel);

  XSetFunction(mydisplay,mygc,GXcopy);

  XSetLineAttributes(mydisplay,mygc,10,LineSolid,CapProjecting,JoinMiter);

  XDrawLine(mydisplay,mywindow,mygc,100,100,400,400);

  XDrawLine(mydisplay,mywindow,mygc,100,400,400,100);

  XFlush(mydisplay);

  sleep(10);

  XCloseDisplay(mydisplay);

  exit(0);
}
```

I can only guess that need to set something, but have no idea where is that option.

Comment: Launch it in debugger, e.g. `gdb`. Then after the segfault happens you will be able to see where that happened, and find the reason.

Comment: I got: "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400b00 in main () at myprog.c:21
21         myscreen = DefaultScreen(mydisplay); "
Well, that doesn't help too much

Comment: Remember, segfaults are one of the easiest problems to debug ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall always check whether functions returned successfully, or not. It is not a Haskell, where all the checking done for you by monad, it is C. As for your particular case, the problem is that the function `XOpenDisplay` fails and returns null for you. In the next line you're trying to use `DefaultScreen` with the result. The `DefaultScreen` is defined as

```
#define DefaultScreen(dpy)  ((dpy)->default_screen)
```

I.e. it just a macro, which using the first argument as a pointer. In your case it does `((0)->default_screen)`, i.e. it dereferencing the null pointer, and that leads to the segfault you see.

Also, about the `XOpenDisplay("192.168.0.12:0");` — you didn't mentioned that you're trying to connect to another PC, so, if it's the same computer where the app running, try to call the function as `XOpenDisplay("127.0.0.1:0");`

**UPD:** okay, I tried to run the code at my PC, and the function doesn't work for me too. To find the reason I started the code under `strace` app, and saw

```
…
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(6000), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
…
```

Aha! So, the app trying to connect to XServer, but Xserver refuses the connection. Actually, it have a security reason to disable it by default — so, that nobody would connect to your XServer from a network unless you specifically allowed it. For the function to work you need to launch your XServer with the option that allows such a connection. Right now DisplayManagers are the ones, who manages xsessions, so you need to set some option depending on your DM.

**The solution for lightdm**

Open the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, and paste the line `xserver-allow-tcp=true` in the section `[SeatDefaults]`*(you will see it)*.

**The solution for gdm**

Edit the file `/etc/gdm/gdm.schemas`, you will find there something like

```
<schema>
<key>security/DisallowTCP</key>
<signature>b</signature>
<default>true</default>
</schema>
```

Change the `true` to `false`.

Comment: Thx for answer. Yes, I'm trying run program on the same comp. I changed ip to 127.0.0.1:0 and still error above. I just don't know why when I use without any ip ("") it's fine, but when trying to put any of ips from ifconfig it's core dump. I tried to run on virtual machine Ubuntu 15.04 and still it's not working.